# Where the new folder is created when using Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Please help me understand where the new folder is created. When I `docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash` the container, the created folder is not there.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir -p /new_folder
COPY . .
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w 4", "main:app"]
```

I also tried copying the local stuff before creating a new folder, still can't see the folder created in the container.

Comment: you have to mount volume while building your docker. Refer to this link for more clarity
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: I'd expect the directory to be created in the image filesystem in the specified path.  If you `docker run --rm your-image ls /`, is it there?  If not, how are you running the container?

Answer (score 1):

your working directory is /app and you are copying files from your current dierctory to /app. when your container is running do this

```
docker exec -it <container_id> pwd
```

you'll see /app in output
but you are creating new_folder as a root directory. so you can't see it inside /app
[image]

to see your root directories you can run this:

```
docker exec -it container_id /bin/sh -c "ls -lah ..
```

also my Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /new_folder
COPY . .
CMD ["python" , "-c" , "import time; time.sleep(10000)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your folder is created at the filesystem root : `/`

try `docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash` and then, in the container, `ls /`